# Compiling Multiple file in C with VS Code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors

well, I have been trying to run a code in Vs Code but the terminal says, "undefined reference to ... " which looks like because it's unable to link the other .c files even though everything is in the same directory.
How can I fix this?
Thanks in Advance.

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\erdo\AppData\Local\Temp\ccwq7JRI.o:main.c:(.text+0x79): undefined reference to `showlist'
```

```
PS E:\Programming C\2022exam> cd "e:\Programming C\2022exam\" ; if ($?) { gcc main.c -o main } ; if ($?) { .\main }
```

I have 3 .c files but it shows that gcc is taking only the main.c, if I am not wrong.

Comment: Are you passing every c file into the compiler argument?

Comment: I guess no, and that's what I need to do, most probably. and I don't know how can I do that!

Comment: I'm guessing this is how you're compiling? `if ($?) { gcc main.c -o main } ;` if so, then put your other C files in there, eg: `if ($?) { gcc main.c fileone.c filetwo.c -o main } ;`

Comment: exactly, you are great mam. It worked seamlessly. Thanks a lot. But It didn't ask for any input just showing some values without asking. Could you give some advice on that?

Comment: I'm assuming you have a json file configured to invoke the compiler. Maybe take a look inside the json?